# Have applications in bluemix on multiple zones, if one zone is down, redirect immediately on the other

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have my website on Bluemix and all of yesterday they EU region was down. I want to know if it is possible to have another instance on US or Sydney and then, if one is down, automatically redirect to the next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The platform doesn't have such a feature to automatically redirect to applications in other regions on error conditions. Applications in other regions are treated as separate applications.

Optimally, to handle rare conditions like the one this weekend, you can create a load balancer with something like NGINX or HAProxy outside of bluemix to direct to the best/available geography.

For example: https://www.howtoforge.com/high-availability-load-balancer-haproxy-heartbeat-debian-etch

Answer (score 1):

It has been necessary for IBM to re-start its Bluemix servers this weekend due to an urgent security patch. The IBM recommendation is to take advantage of the capability to have multiple application instances deployed in the different regions, as indicated in Ram's answer.

The maintenance phase in the EU-GB and Sydney regions is now complete. It is ongoing for the US region. For the latest updates and details on this maintenance, check http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus.

Comment: This answerer actually seems to be some maintainer from the host in op's question. Most definitely pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

In order to integrate the Vennam response, you could create a load balancer in bluemix using containers (or VM) (of course this workaround doesn't work if containers are down) but you can install NGINX or HAProxy. You could also use Bluemix containers as environment test before moving your load balancer on outside server.